# Injectivity from L1(S1) to Co(Z)

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Let

$$c_0(\mathbb{Z}) = \left\{(\alpha_n)_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} : \lim_{\lvert n\rvert\to\infty} \alpha_n = 0\right\}$$

be the vector space of null sequences.

Define the Fourier transform which sends every function $f\in L^1(S^1)$ to sequence of Fourier coefficients of $f$, show that Fourier transform is injective.

To solve this problem I have showed that if all the Fourier coefficients of a function $f\in L^1(S^1)$ are zero then $f=0$ a.e, then how the above defined map is injective! May be I am missing some silly points, please guide me.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tYybO.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! As this site is meant to be a useful repository rather than a Do My Homework forum, it's common courtesy to show what you've already tried, and really narrow down what you're struggling with. Most people here are glad to help once you've adequately motivated the problem. [Quick Guide](http://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/34067/21813) to attracting answers and preventing your question from being deleted. Good luck!

Comment: $L^1$ is usually defined as a set of *equivalence classes* of integrable functions under the equivalence relation that $f\sim g$ iff $f=g$ almost everywhere. So when we say something like *Let $f\in L^1(X,\mathscr{A},\mu)$*, what we really mean is that $[f]\in L^1(X,\mathscr{A},\mu)$, where $[f]$ is the equivalence class of $f$ under the equivalence relation defined above. This is what we need to turn $L^1$ into a normed vector space, and so if you find that $f=g$ a.e., then this means that they both identify the same equivalence class, and so you don't get a problem.

Comment: @Lorago thanks , now I understand.